# Getting the last part of the string

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string :

```
 "id=40114662&mode=Edit&reminderId=44195234"
```

All i want from this string is the final number  44195234.  I can't use :

```
    String reminderIdFin = reminderId.substring(reminderId.lastIndexOf("reminderId=")+1);
```

as i cant have the = sign as the point it splits the string.  Is there any other way ?

Comment: Can you use `String.lastIndexOf("=")` to get the last `=` index then use it when calling `substring()`?

Comment: Use either `reminderId.substring(reminderId.lastIndexOf("=")+1);` or `reminderId.substring(reminderId.lastIndexOf("reminderId=")+"reminderId=".length());` whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try `String.split()`,

```
reminderIdFin.split("=")[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything else and you'll be left with your target content:

```
String reminderIdFin = reminderId.replaceAll(".*=", "");
```

The regex matches everything up to the last `=` (the `.*` is "greedy").

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf() method to get where this part starts:

```
int index = reminderIdFin.indexOf("Id=") + 3;
```

the plus 3 will make it so that it jumps over these characters. Then you can use substring to pull out your wanted string:

```
String newString = reminderIdFin.substring(index);
```